# What's wrong with Query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So locally I have

```
@fooentries = Entry.where(:status => 'foo').where("created_at >= #{Date.today}")
```

Which runs fine, but when I deploy to Heroku it seems to be breaking it.

I asked a friend and he told me to do the following but this fails locally:

```
@fooentries = Entry.where(:status => 'foo').where("created_at >= #{Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day.to_s(:db)}")
```

Anyone?

EDIT: Doesn't matter, fixed it. This is what the query needs to be-

```
@fooentries = Entry.where(:status => 'foo').where('entries.created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

Comment: What error messages are you receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Would you try to escape the query, maybe it depends on the format your query is built
try

```
@fooentries = Entry.where(:status => 'foo').where("created_at >= ?", Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the edit above, this is what I needed -

```
@fooentries = Entry.where(:status => 'foo').where('entries.created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```